# Dynamic Links not quite as the Firebase doc says

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, xcode8

I am now looking at the `Firebase` documentation in this section [Create Dynamic Links on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create).

Two things don't happen for me as they are supposed to in the presentation video.

1. In this part of the video (13:30~14:00), the appStore opens, but for me it doesn't.
   When I click on the link while the app is not installed, I get to choose between opening the link with Safari or installing Chrome. Even if I then choose to open with Safari, I still need to perform a couple of clicks before actually reaching the appStore.
2. In this part of the video (14:00~14:15), the app is launched from Xcode, and one can see in the debugging console that the function *func application(:, open:, options:)* is called, but for me it doesn't get called.

In case this may be relevant, I am using Xcode Version 8.3.2 and experimenting using an iPhone 6 with iOS  Version 10.3.2.

I wonder if I am doing something wrong or if the documentation is just not quite complete.

Any tip about how I should handle this situation will be very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This overview video is a year old now — a few things have changed in the meantime.

1. Apple [added a security alert in iOS 10.3](https://blog.branch.io/the-ios-10-3-security-alert-is-killing-app-store-downloads/) that requires extra clicks. It's no longer possible to go directly to the App Store without these clicks, though I've not run into invites to install Chrome before...would be interesting in seeing replication steps for how you're getting those.
2. This is confusing, and I've never been able to determine exactly what is getting called when. Fortunately, so long as you get the link object back, it doesn't really matter where it came from. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672308/5394680) for more discussion of this.

Comment: I see, thanks for the information, but that's a bad news. The point was to be simple and direct right? Run-the-app or Go-GetIt-onTheStore, That simplification gone brings down the charm by one fold. Anyway about Chrome (I don't have it on my device), I got this choice when I cliked the dynamic link I had made, that's all.

Comment: For the 2nd point you are right "so long as you get the link object back, it doesn't really matter where it came from". For me the problem is that I don't get it back anywhere I can see.

Comment: It's an Apple limitation, so this applies to ALL apps unfortunately. Where are you clicking the dynamic link? In which app? And could you post your full AppDelegate?

Comment: I am clicking it in my mail client on my iPhone.

Comment: I think I am close to find a solution,  I just realized the FIROptions.default().deepLinkURLScheme was not set properly and it seems to make a significant difference. Thanks a lot for all your tips.